# Salesforce Merge related records transfer

Tags: apex, person-accounts, merge

,

I'm hoping to find out if anyone has or knows where to find an official list of which related  "child" objects will be transferred during an apex merge of Person Accounts.

My tests show successful transfer of Cases, (on both AccountId and ContactId)

but Opportunities were not transferred, nor Contact Point Phone records (using ParentId -> AccountId) .

I've been searching for an official list, so as to know where the gaps are and what should be done manually.

Haven't found anything yet. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail about the child records after the merge - are they orphaned (i.e. Account field is blank)?  Also, have you opened a case with Salesforce?